# Making a messagebox with countdown and application launch batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, messagebox

Needing there to be a delay for an application to start. I need to write a batch file that displays a popup message that reads "POS WILL LOAD IN %xx% SECONDS. PLEASE WAIT..."

I would like it if the %xx% could countdown, but if it remains static, that's okay. Once the 20 seconds has passed, I need the batch script to call the application I need and then close.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: This.. @echo off

echo MsgBox "POS LOADING IN 20 SECONDS. PLEASE WAIT..." >> msg.vbs 
 call msg.vbs 
 del msg.vbs 

timeout 20

exit

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
@echo off
@echo WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "I will dissapear in 5 seconds", 5 > %TEMP%\wait.vbs 
wscript %TEMP%\wait.vbs
echo done
```

Instead of a .vbs make a .hta

```
@echo off
%temp%\wait.hta
echo done
```

Make the file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Wait</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION APPLICATIONNAME="PleaseWait" ID="PleaseWait" VERSION="1.00" SYSMENU="no" MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no" MINIMIZEBUTTON="no" SCROLL="no" />
</head>
<script language="VBScript">
Sub Window_OnLoad
    window.resizeTo 300, 100
    window.moveTo (window.screen.width - 300) / 2, (window.screen.height - 100) / 2
End Sub
</script>
<script language="Javascript">
var count = 5, counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
function timer() {
    if ((count -= 1) <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        window.close();
    } 
    document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = count;
}
</script>
<body>
<h2>Wait <span id="secs"></span></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable or hide the OK button? I want to force them to stay at the message the full time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a routine posted in 2007 that I modified:

```
@echo off 
cls & echo.
set "text=....Waiting for 20 seconds...."
call :animate
set "text=....Waiting for 10 seconds...."
call :animate
set "text=Running application..."
call :animate

Rem Startup routine goes here
pause
goto :EOF


:animate
:: calculate the length of the text string
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (
'^(for %%i in ^("%text%" .^) do @echo %%i^) ^| findstr /o .^| ^
findstr /v /b 0') do set /a v=%%~a-5

for /L %%a in (1,1,%v%) do call set "txt=%%text:~0,%%a%%"&call :show out
echo %text%
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
cls & echo.
for /L %%a in (2,1,%v%) do call set "txt=%%text:~%%a%%"&call :show in
goto :EOF

:show
for %%a in (/ - \ ^| / - \ ^|) do (
if %1==out echo %txt%^%%a
if %1==in  echo ^%%a%txt%
for /L %%b in (1,1,1000) do set dummy=%%b
cls & echo.
)
goto :EOF
```